# Finding the mean value of a Pareto Distribution.

Tags: probability, statistics, expected-value, density-function

The question:

Quality control experts estimate that the time (in years) until a specific electronic part from an assembly line fails follows a Pareto density of the form $f(x) = 3/x^{4}$ for $1 < x \leq{\infty}$.

What is the approximate mean failure time?

My current attempt starts with the following:

$E[X] = \int_{1}^{\infty}xf(x)dx = \int_{1}^{\infty}x3x^{-4}dx = -x^{-3}$.

Is this antiderivative correct? And given the bounds of $1$ to $\infty$, how can I determine an approximate mean time from this?

Comment: The antiderivative is $-3 x^{-2}/2$. Now use the fundamental theorem of calculus.  You will get the exact mean.

Comment: From a practical point of view it seems strange that the time until an electronic part fails follows a distribution where the probability that this time is less than one is zero and then peaks  suddenly. Unless: this is [planned obsolescence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planned_obsolescence).

Comment: @KurtG. Ok, I think I know what I'm supposed to do.  Evaluating the limit as x approaches infinity should give me 0, and evaluating the CDF at 1 should give me -1.5, and subtracting the two should give me 1.5 minutes on average.

Comment: Years, not minutes (see OP).

Comment: woops, thanks for that.

Comment: Your density is a Pareto distribution with parameters $\alpha=3$ and $x_\min = 1$.  For $\alpha > 1$ the mean is $\frac{\alpha}{\alpha-1}x_\min$ which is indeed $1.5$ years here.  In your integration it would probably be more usual to write something like $\int_{1}^{\infty}x3x^{-4}dx = \left.-x^{-3}\right|^\infty_1 = \frac32$

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the fact that for a nonnegative random variable $X$
$$
\mathbb E[X] = \int_0^\infty (1-F(x))\ \mathsf dx,
$$
where $F$ is the cumulative distribution function of $X$.
So here
$$
\mathbb E[X] = \int_1^\infty x^{-3}\ \mathsf dx = \frac12.
$$